# How to return a modified result in a promise as a promise

Tags: swift, promisekit

I'm using promiseKit 6 with the extensions for Alamofire. In the function bellow I'm looking to return `Promise<JSON>` (I use swiftyJson) but the response from the alamofire call is a Promise containing a tuple: `Promise<(json: Any, response: PMKAlamofireDataResponse)>`

when I get that from the first then, how can I continue to return just the json part? thanks :)

```
return firstly {
  self.requestClient.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON()
}.then { arg in
  let (json, rsp) = arg
  return json
}
```

I also get this error: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Promise<_.T>' to return type 'Promise<JSON>'`
on the line: `}.then { arg in ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast Any to JSON, try this (not tested), but documentation said you could use map/compactMap https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md

```
return firstly {
    self.requestClient.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, 
          encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON()
}.compactMap { data, rsp in
   return data as? JSON
}
```

Comment: I'm using The promisekit alamofire extension so the request returns a promise of type: `Promise<(json: Any, response: PMKAlamofireDataResponse)>` when you call responseJSON() on it, I've updated the question

Comment: I think it's a compiler type problem, but can you try the syntax I've updated ? you could try to infer the promise type too

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try it

Comment: How it's going on ?

Comment: worked out for me, had to remove the `in` from firstly though.